# BIOS-e820 in dmesg - How do I calculate the memory range from addresses

Tags: linux, memory, bios, dmesg

```
kp@localhost ~]$ sudo dmesg | grep -i "e820"
```

results in the following output:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009d7ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009d80000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a209fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a20a000-0x000000000affffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b000000-0x000000000b01ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000dd082fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dd083000-0x00000000dd1ebfff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dd1ec000-0x00000000dd36dfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dd36e000-0x00000000dd781fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dd782000-0x00000000de65afff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000de65b000-0x00000000deffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000df000000-0x00000000dfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd100000-0x00000000fdffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fea00000-0x00000000fea0ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feb80000-0x00000000fec01fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec30000-0x00000000fec30fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed40000-0x00000000fed44fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedc2000-0x00000000fedcffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedd4000-0x00000000fedd5fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000feefffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f37ffff] usable
```

I want to understand the technique to calculate the actual range of memory represented by [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f37ffff] for instance.

I some tutorial I found 0x100000000 represents 4GiB and 0x3ffffffff represents 16GiB. But I could not derive the way it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are hexadecimal values. You can use a programmer’s calculator or even Bash to convert them to decimal:

```
echo $((0x100000000))
```

To convert to mebibytes or gibibytes, divide accordingly:

```
$ echo $((0x100000000/1024/1024))
4096
$ echo $((0x21f37ffff/1024/1024))
8691
```

Thus 0x100000000 is indeed 4GiB, and 0x21f37ffff is nearly 8.5GiB (8704MiB), so 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f37ffff is the range from 4GiB to nearly 8.5GiB.

Comment: bash accepts 0x3ffffffff in expressions, so no need to use the 16#3ffffffff syntax.

Comment: galculator I was using in linux for hex numbers did not have the precision to show so many digits in decimal!